# Fastest way to concatenate many text files in a given directory

Tags: files-and-directories

I have about 1 million .txt text files in a directory which I would like to all concatenate in one single text file (separated by a newline character "\n"). Because of the number of files and their size I would rather not like to read everything in memory first. So I was wondering - what is the fastest way to do this in Mathematica, without having to resort to read everything in memory first?

cheers, 
Tom

Comment: If you have Unix tools available, just `cat *.txt > hugefile.txt` is sufficient to join the files.

Comment: Yes that's true, good point - although in my application, it would be nice if I could do it from within Mathematica

Comment: There's `OpenAppend`.  Basically I'm thinking you could append one file at a time.  Or you might use Unix tools from within *Mathematica*.

Comment: If you really want to do it from within Mathematica you can still use cormullions suggestion: `Run["cat *.txt > hugefile.txt"]`.

Comment: Yes good idea - but there is no command line option in cat by any chance that will allow me to insert a next line character between each file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way:

```
Clear[copy, merge];
copy[file1_, out_OutputStream] := Module[{input},
   input = Check[Import[file1, "Text"], Return[$Failed]];
   BinaryWrite[out, input];
   BinaryWrite[out, "\n"];
   ];

merge[files_List, outFile_String] := Module[{out},
  Check[out = OpenWrite[outFile, BinaryFormat -> True], Return[$Failed]];
  Do[copy[in, out], {in, files}];
  Close[out];
  ]
```

Example use:

```
merge[
 FileNames[DigitCharacter ~~ ".txt", {"/tmp"}],
 "/tmp/foo.txt"
 ]
```

I'm not sure how to analyze its speed.

Comment: Ha many thanks - that's great!!

Answer (score 9):

To regularly run terminal stuff from within Mathematica use `CellEvaluationFunction` as described by WReach on this site.

Step 1 set up a cell style:

```
Cell[StyleData["Terminal"],
 CellFrame->2,
 ShowGroupOpener->False,
 CellMargins->{{66, 4}, {10, 8}},
 Evaluatable->True,
 StripStyleOnPaste->True,
 CellEvaluationFunction->Function[{$CellContext`x, $CellContext`y}, 
   Import[
    StringExpression["!", $CellContext`x], "Text"]],
 CellFrameColor->GrayLevel[0.5],
 Hyphenation->False,
 AutoQuoteCharacters->{},
 PasteAutoQuoteCharacters->{},
 LanguageCategory->"Formula",
 ScriptLevel->1,
 MenuSortingValue->1800,
 FontFamily->"Monaco",
 FontSize->13,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Plain",
 FontColor->RGBColor[0, 1, 0],
 Background->GrayLevel[0]]
```

[image]

Step 2 run a terminal command e.g.

> open -a "QuickTime Player"

[image]

or

> cat *.txt > hugefile.txt