# How to determine if directories with executable permission and not

Tags: mathematical-optimization, expression-test

I have some directories that have the UNIX executable permission some does not.  What tests could I write in Mathematica to test it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger UNIX command-line command from Mathematica notebook?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63174/how-to-trigger-unix-command-line-command-from-mathematica-notebook)

Comment: `ReadList["!ls -la ~/somedie", String]` lists the `-rwx--x--x` on all files. I assume that's what you mean by "UNIX executable permission"?

Comment: That relies on seeing UNIX permission values directly.  Any "indirect" way?  I want to see if I can "execute" anything in the directory.  But how to test this "execute" in Mathematica?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to execute a file and see if it's executable or not?

Comment: the linux executable bit for directories does not affect executability of files within the directory. Nice explanation here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened

Comment: If you have read permission, but not execute then you *should* be able to get a listing with `FileNames`, but *any* file access on any file ( eg. `FileDate` ) should fail. ( sorry my linux box is down so I can't test ). Of course if you don't have read permission either than its kind of moot.

Comment: following up on my comment, `FileNames[__,dir]` just returns an empty list if *dir* is not executable (even though `ls` will show the directory contents ), so you cant use this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I understand well, but if you want to check, with Mathematica on Unix, if a given file/directory is executable, you'll have to run a specific external unix command line and retrieve the result.

#### Unix useful commands

*The following concerns UNIX systems but there are probably some equivalent commands for Windows. (Feel free to edit the post if you know which ones).*

There are several ways ... such as the approach given by @Oska in the comments above (-> analyse the file explicit permissions output by `ls -la`).

Here I will use the UNIX `test` command which in particular can be applied directly to a file to check many of its properties. Indeed, to check if a file is executable, just type in a terminal the command line :
`test -x filename` or `[ -x filename ]` (`[`the square bracket is a shorthand of `test`but the you have to add `]` at the end of the test.) The `-x` option is actually telling `test` to check if the file is indeed executable (many other options exists, just see the manual pages of test).

#### Run the external (unix) command with Mathematica :`Run`, `RunProcess`, `ReadList` and `Import`

There are also different ways to ask Mathematica to run an external command AND to get back the result (into Mathematica). I will show below how to run our unix `test` command with all the Mathematica functions given in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63174/how-to-trigger-unix-command-line-command-from-mathematica-notebook).

```
execQ[filename_] := Run["test -x " <> filename] == 0
```

or

```
execQ[filename_] := RunProcess[{$SystemShell, "-c", "test -x " <> filename}, "ExitCode"] == 0
```

or

```
execQ[filename_] := ReadList["!test -x " <> filename <> " && echo 0 || echo 1"] == {0};
```

or

```
execQ[filename_] := Import["!test -x " <> filename <> " && echo 0 || echo 1", "Text"] == "0";
```

This indeed will test only if the filename corresponds to a file which is executable. It works for regular files and directories. I could have included here some additional unix code to test if the file is also a directory (`test -d` will do) but I leave it to Mathematica which knows how to do that also with `FileType`. (See the tests below).

You'll notice some additional unix command `&& echo 0 || echo 1` for `ReadList`and `Import`. This will print on a unix terminal 0 or 1, depending whether the test was successful or not. This is required here as those mathematica functions cannot retrieve (contrary to `Run`and `RunProcess`) the equivalent "exit codes" returned automatically by the unix.

#### Test

Let's apply the function `execQ` to your problem :

1/ let's for example list automatically all the directories in the current working directory (`Directory[]`) :

```
mydirs = Select[FileNames[], FileType@# == Directory &]
```

2/ then, this should tell you which ones are executable :

```
Select[mydirs, execQ]
```

#### Explanation concerning the `RunProcess` code

As requested by the OP in the comments, here are some explanations concerning the `RunProcess` syntax inside `execQ`.
"-c" and "-x" are actually options for two different UNIX commands used here.
What happens  :

- `RunProcess`  sends an external command to the operating system command language interpreter `$SystemShell` (try to evaluate that variable in a cell in Mathematica).
- The `-c` option (which is specific to the Unix shell), tells that the command sent to the interpreter is contained in a string which is actually the third argument in the list inside my `RunProcess` code.
- The unix command sent in the string here is : `test -x`, which actually tests if the given `filename` is executable (`-x`). If it is, the command will return the exit code 0, or 1 if it is not.
- This exit code is then **directly** retrieved by Mathematica thanks to the parameter `"ExitCode"` given in the `RunProcess` command.

For more info about the unix commands, you can just type in a unix console/terminal `man sh` and `man test` or just google it.

Comment: What is "-c" and "-x" for respectively?  What's documentation for those?  The answer is incomplete without any mentioning of such.

Comment: @qazwsx Please, see my edit.

Comment: just `Run[" test -x dirname" ]` works as well, for those with older versions..

Comment: @george2079 yes ;) actually I have prepared yesterday a small edit to my answer to show all the alternative ways to do the same thing, including `Run` (as you exactly did), but also `ReadList`, and `Import`. I also planned to replace `[ ]`with `test` which is a little bit less "scary" ;) I'll post that very soon.

Comment: @george2079 Please see my edit with added alternative ways to run the same external `test` command. `Run` and others are now included.