# Run external program

Tags: external-calls

I need to run an external program to process some files. I have added the location of the program to my .bash_profile (I use a mac) and I have verified that executing the program in Terminal works.

However, whenever I execute `Run["program"]` Mathematica returns 32512. I suppose this is some error code but I can't find what it means.

Whatever idea you have will help me.

Comment: Try the answers in this question [how-to-trigger-unix-command-line-command-from-mathematica-notebook](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63174/how-to-trigger-unix-command-line-command-from-mathematica-notebook) Same error code there. This code looks like the exit code from the program you ran.

Comment: I think that code is either coming from the OS or Mathematica, since I get the same output no matter what I `Run`.

Comment: try running a system command, like "ls" or "dir" and see if you get same code. It works for me when I do `Run["DIR"]` no problem.

Comment: you were right, "ls" returns 0, could it be that Mathematica is not finding the program I'm trying to run?

Comment: `RunProcess` will return an `Association` with more status info about the program you tried to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is likely to be that the program you are trying to run is not on the path that Mathematica is using.  To see this you can use:

```
file = CreateTemporary[];
Run[StringJoin["echo $PATH >", file]];
FilePrint[file]
```

I get the following

> ```
> /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.0/Executables:/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.0/SystemFiles/Graphics/Binaries/Linux-x86-64:/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.0/Executables:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/bin/X11
> ```

Comment: right, I get only `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, even when I edit my .bash_profile to add the path of the program I want to run...

Comment: Can you specify the full path to the program in the call e.g. `Run["/path/to/program"]`?  Or use `Run["bash -c Program"]`?

Comment: `Run` with the full path works. What does `bash -c program` do?

Comment: It uses bash to run the program.  If you have set up the path correctly for bash, it should then be able to launch the program.